# Check multiple cells and message box if data missing

Tags: excel, vba, message

Is there a way to check multiple ranges, if they are blank then display a message box and tell me which ones have data missing? At the moment I'm typing this out and doing loads of different ones. Was wondering if there is an easier way?

My range is: Range("C11:D11,F11:G11,I11:J11,C14:F14,I14:J14,C15:F15,I15:J15,B18:J18,B42:J42"))

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C9:E9")) = 0 Then
 Worksheets("Create Form").Range("C9:E9").Select
 MsgBox "Please enter information in the required fields."
 Exit Sub
End If

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("H9:J9")) = 0 Then
 Worksheets("Create Form").Range("H9:J9").Select
 MsgBox "Please enter information in the required fields."
 Exit Sub
End If
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to check multiple Range, and in the code below it is implemented by using a `For` loop through all `Areas` of that Range.

Then for each `CurRng` (represnting an area), check if `WorksheetFunction.CountA(CurRng) = 0`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckMultipleRanges()

Dim MyMultiRng      As Range
Dim CurRng          As Range

With Worksheets("Create Form")   
   ' use a variable to set the multiple ranges in it 
   Set MyMultiRng = .Range("C11:D11,F11:G11,I11:J11,C14:F14,I14:J14,C15:F15,I15:J15,B18:J18,B42:J42")

   ' loop through all areas in the multi-range
    For Each CurRng In MyMultiRng.Areas
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(CurRng) = 0 Then
            CurRng.Select
            MsgBox "Please enter information in the required fields."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next CurRng
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You're a star :) Thank you

Comment: Sorry just noticed it doesnt allow me to highlight the cell where the error occurs. Is there a way to select the cell and is there a way to incorporate a message box with it?

Comment: @ShawnCartwright did you see my code ? `rest of your code goes here` ,give me 5 and yes

Comment: I did thank you. Im looking to have it reference and select the cell that is blank if that is possible. The code you have provided is excellent though.

Comment: @ShawnCartwright try now the edited code, let me know if it works as youintended